# After creating dynamic table rows issue in the click event

Tags: android, dynamic

Hi i am developing android application. I that i have creating the dynamic table rows which have the same textviews as per the new messages. If i have 2 new Messages it will display like this. [here is my code of dynamic data display](http://pastebin.com/JGK6Frzd)
E.g rows like this 
             New Messages

Sender: rony

Ack: joseph,mike

Message : hi how are you.

Now there is another new message which have,

Sender: kushal

Ack: dhrum,dyna

Message : i am fine.

Now the Ack: textview is clickable. It is for the acknowledgement. But i can only acknowledgement the last message. I want to acknowledgement all the new message one by one but i won't be able to do it. I regret if my english and the flow of exlpaination is poor. please do help me.

Comment: where do you set your text to these `TextView`'s and perform `onClick()`. show us your code also.

Comment: i am performing onclick but it only acknowledge last new message.

Comment: [come here for chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1531/casual-chat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will do something like this:

```
tvAck.setTag(taskInvolvementId);
```

and in your `onClick()` you will get Id like this way:

```
tvAck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
            String taskInvolvementId = (String)v.getTag();
            Log.d("taskInvolvementId is ", taskInvolvementId);
      }
```